# How to customize/ extend ootb components in spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am new to Spartacus and I am trying to add more elements to the component AddedToCartDialogComponent. Not sure how I can customise/extend this component.

I need to extend the typescript and also the template which is the view for this component.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Suma -  Did you find anything regarding AddedToCartDialogComponent customization?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your best bet is reading through the Spartacus docs about customizing components [here](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/). Also try to find your answer in other places in our docs.

If your question was about extending components from Angular perspective, you should probably first read [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components)